# Using UI router, how to pass parameters to url without altering the state?

Tags: angularjs

In my controller, I use $state.go('home', {"parameters": paramValue, "parameter1": another value, "parameters3": another another value}, {reload:true}); and while this does attempt to go to the home state and passes the parameters to the url, the home state view keeps loading. If I copy the url with the parameters passed, and click enter, everything loads properly.

This is the process of going to the home tab. 
 -> the url changes to reflect that home state is trying to be reached
 -> a second reload occurs when the url gets the parameters passed. The parameters do get passed successfully.
 -> It keeps trying to load the home view. 
 The url is correct and works( parameters and all); as I can copy the link and access it. I've also toggled with reload to false. 
Should I try transitionTo?

Answer (score 0):

Hey all for anyone else having a similar kind of problem. The answer to stop the unneccessary reloading is to add the `notify:false` to `state.go('main.home', params, {notify:false});`